# C# Encrypt and Decrypt DLL on the fly

Tags: c#, dll, encryption

We are developing a client/server based application that should encrypt the DLLs on the server side then during the client installation phase the server would send these DLLs to the client.

When the Client is running, it will remotely connect to the server to get the decrypting key. Then it would decrypt the DLLs and use them to launch and use the program.

My problem is not to encrypt the DLLs, but how may I decrypt them on-the-fly to be usable?

Appreciate for your time.
Camille.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a fairly broad question; try asking something more specific.

Comment: We don't want to put all the DLLs along with the Installer. We would like to provide these encrypted DLLs during the activation time, after the server has checked if the client is a valid one. So basically, I don't see how is it possible to decrypt on-the-fly these DLLs with AES to be used in our software. We won't be able to add these references, because the files will be encrypted and only decrypted during the launch of the program....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to download and decrypt the DLL file, and then load the DLL at runtime using things from the `System.Reflection` namespace such as `Assembly.Load` and `CreateInstance`.

Nevertheless, I don't think this is all that secure.  Always keep in mind that you do not control the client.

Comment: Thus, would you have any suggestions that could enhance the process? What about keeping the DLLs on the server side, and load them over a SSL tunnel between the client and the server?

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, I might use some sort of webservice.  This way I could authenticate them, and code that I don't want the users to have would run on my servers, not on the untrusted client.  They would just have to make requests to it and get responses.

Comment: Just to be clear. You would make a webservice that contains critical operations/methods. Then the client would contact this webservice everytime they need to use these critical methods. Is that right?

Comment: Correct.  There is overhead with this, of course, which is why I said it depends on circumstances.  Otherwise, if I send them my code (even if encrypted), they can get to it... it has to be decrypted at some point to run on the client CPU.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are inventing a new type of security scheme, rather than using tried-and-tested techniques. Unless you are a security professional, you may end up with a complex system that does not protect your software.

Your question just leads to more questions:

If you are sending DLLs with the decryption key, why even encrypt them in the first place?

What is the definition and proposed benefit of "on-the-fly"?

Are you planning on having some sort of expiration mechanism? Once the client has the decryption key, you have to assume they have it forever.

Comment: Could you please lead me to the tried-and-tested techniques scheme? Actually, we want the client program to connect our server using SSL to be authenticated. This is no problem. Problem is, the client program might be easily patched to skip this phase. We would like to secure our code, to not let it patched.

Comment: @Camille, the solution however isn't very simple. Using SSL only protect the data for external observers, meaning that the data sent through the wire will be encrypted. However, a malicious user with access to a legitimate client could capture the encryption seed and decrypt dlls himself.

Comment: @Bruno, is a program can easily be patched? By patched I mean that any attachers could edit the source code, skip the authentication code and re-compile the program without authentication?

Comment: @Camille, most certainly. Any kind of client authentication will very easily lead to cracks. Even the most obfuscated code will.

Comment: @Camille, the thing about security is the same as putting locks in your house. That doesn't really keep the thieves out, but if your lock is stronger than your neighbor's, they might leave you alone for a while. However, the proposed solution isn't very secure. If you simply transmit the key to the client code, and you are using a symmetrical key, even with SSL a malicious user can create a fake client with legitimate credentials and intercept the key.

Comment: @Bruno, thank you for your explanation. What about putting some operations on the server side (webservice) that could authenticate the client on every operations? The hacker won't access to the code on the server side, and it would be transparent for the user.

Comment: @Camille: And how would you authenticate the client on the server?